# Execute the code instead of throwing error

Tags: r

I have a data frame where I am trying to subset the columns.
Incase if I give "undefined columns", it should be display the output

```
datf <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,3,4), c = c(7,6,5))
datf[c('a','b', 'v')]
Error in `[.data.frame`(datf, c("a", "b", "v")) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Expected output

```
datf[c('a','b', 'v')]
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 3
3 3 4
```

So basically, if there defined columns then fine, or else it should exclude the undefined column and execute the code? Is this possible?

Comment: What about `datf[colnames(datf) %in% c('a','b', 'v')]`? And if you prefer the columns to be ordered in the same way as in the vector, then use `datf[c('a','b', 'v')[c('a','b', 'v')  %in%  colnames(datf)]]`

Comment: No no... The code ````datf[c('a','b', 'v')]```` is a long one and is dynamic. I just have to exclude undefined columns

Comment: Read about intersect: `datf[ , intersect(colnames(datf), c("a", "b", "v")) ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zx8754 also suggested in the comments, you can use `intersect` like this:

```
cols <- c('a','b', 'v')
output <- datf[intersect(names(datf), cols)]
output
```

Output:

```
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 3
3 3 4
```